# Who composed the stotra on Ramanujacharya starting "Punyambhoja Vikasaya"?

Tags: identification-request, sri-vaishnava, ramanujacharya, stotra

I heard a stotra in the opening credits of Tamil movie [*Ramanujacharya*](https://youtu.be/h1AgTelmYWc) which hails Sri Ramanujacharya starting with "Punyambhoja vikasaya" The stanzas which I could understand are as follows.

> Punyāmbhoja vikasāya pāpadhvānta kśayāyaca ।
>   ṣrīmānāvirabhūdbhūmou āmānuja divākarah ॥
>
> Meaning : Ramanuja, the sun who rose in this world for blossoming knowledge and remove our sins
>
> yad śruti smṛti sūtrāṇāṃ antarjvaramaśīśayat |
>   tyajīyāt yatirājo'tu rāmānuja divākaraḥ ||
>
> Meaning: The fever(jvaram) for shruti(vedas,upanishads), smriti(gita, puranas), brahmasutra was cured buy a sun called Rāmānuja
>
> bhaktimārga paroyena śāstrasiddha pravaktitaḥ |
>     sajīyāt yatirājo'tu rāmānuja divākaraḥ ||
>
> sarveṣāṃ mokṣalābhāya prapattiḥ yena darśitaḥ |
>     tyajīyāt yatirājo'tu rāmānuja divākaraḥ

(There could be mistakes in these verses since I heard audio and then typed the stotra) This stanza and whole stotra has a makuta (last line which adds beauty to the poem just like a crown adds to a person wearing it) "Ramanuja Divakarah". Here Ramanujacharya is equated with the Sun. 
I found this stanza on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/RamanujaDivarakaha) and total stotra is available in audio format sung by Balamurali Krishna and other singers.

After some research, I could locate the above shloka in [Prarthana Panchakam](https://www.prapatti.com/slokas/telugu/praarthanaapanchakam.pdf) (opens a pdf file on clicking). It is the tenth shloka. But the rest of the shlokas sung in the audio are not found in that pdf. Some discussion forums on the internet state it is a part of Dinacharya written by Erumbi Appa. [Erumbi Appa](https://guruparamparai.wordpress.com/2012/10/27/erumbiappa/) who is also called Devarajaguru is one of the ashta diggajas of Manavala Mamunigal.

Where are these shlokas taken from and what is it called? Which Sri Vaishnava acharya composed this stotra?

Comment: Btw, what is Ramanuja NootrandhAdhi?

Comment: @Paṇḍyā It is Sanskrit.  Divakara is sun. Ramanuja Divakara means Sun named Ramanuja. The shloka means the sun named Ramanuja has incarnated on the earth to remove our sins. Rupaka Samasa is used. It is in ITRANS. Ramanuja NootrandhaAdhi is a work written by Kuresha which is added as a latter portion to 4000 Divya Prabandham. It contains praise of Azhwars and mainly Ramanujacharya.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā A correction, Ramanuja Nootrandadhi is not writte by Kuresha, it's his shishya named Thiruvarangathu Amudhunar. I added meanings of the verses which I could understand.